# Powershell: Additional IP details of Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

I have 4 additional IPs in my azure VM. I need to list all these IPs using a powerShell Command. What is the possible way out ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wha do you mean by the posssible way ut? avoiding powershell you mean?

Comment: No. I want a powershell script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days I came to know addition IP's are listed in vmconfig-file. I was able to create and save vmconfig file using this-

```
$vmName= "xyz"
$srcServiceName = "lmno"
$sourceVm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName $srcServiceName –Name $vmName
$vmConfigurationPath = "C:\MyFolder" + '\' + $vmName +".xml"
$sourceVm | Export-AzureVM -Path $vmConfigurationPath
```

I was able to see additional IP's

[image]

This served my purpose. Thanks.